# How to add different text in each result of foreach?

Tags: php

How can i add different text for each of result in foreach loop

For example

image 1 , "sample text 1", image 2, "sample text2

```
 <?php 
    $id = 51;
    $count = 0;
    $is = get_children("post_parent=$id&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&order_by=ASC");
    foreach($is as $i) {
      $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'full');?>
        <img src="<?php echo $url[0]; ?>">

     <?php 
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: It sounds like a PHP question (not wordpress). check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271169/placing-a-div-or-img-in-between-a-post-array-using-wp-query/271179#271179

Answer (score -1):

You can use the wp_get_attachment_metadata() function which returns an array of data.

I would add it to your code

```
<?php 
$id = 51;
$count = 0;
$is = get_children("post_parent=$id&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&order_by=ASC");
foreach($is as $i) {
  $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'full');
  $attachementMeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($i->ID);
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $url[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $attachementMeta['image_meta']['caption']; ?>">

 <?php 
} 
?>
```

Read more about the wp_get_attachment_metadata() [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

Hope this helps.